# user postgres launches process that takes all CPUs 100% usage

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

User postgres is running a process that take all CPUs at 100% usage in a centos machine, the postgresql service is not running so it cannot be a query.

When I try to stop the process it restarts itself. Then name of the process is somewhat strange.

[image: Information of the running process]

Comment: I dont see how it is postgres from your pic. probably you are mining coins for smbd

Comment: btw taking db offline now is a precious advise. If I were a miner, I would monitor exactly SO to see if I'm caught or not and would destroy my code asap - first to make it harder to protect next time and second I would be extremely ashamed to write the code that uses 100% without even a minimal effort to make it look less suspicious...

Comment: You got hacked.

Comment: @VaoTsun just out of curiosity: how can you tell it is related to coin mining? Just in case I see something similar in the future. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @JimJones just from my ignorance :D I just don't see any other point to spin self written process on somebodies postgres using supposedly  all four cores at max pace. I mean - how else could you use other machine resources? To brute force password? To calculate Pi? As I said - I thought on coins just because my knowledge and fantasy are very limited

Comment: @VaoTsun It indeed makes sense! I just would hardly get to this conclusion so quickly. Thanks for the explanation.. cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations!

By exposing a database with a weak superuser password to the internet you invited somebody to break in and use your CPU for their own purposes, probably [mining crypto-currencies](https://www.hackread.com/hackers-hide-monero-cryptominer-in-scarlett-johansson-picture/).

Take the machine from the internet, wipe it clean and re-install the operating system.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more since to debug the issue, identify the weakness and not repeat it in the future?

Comment: Well, the weakness is the weak superuser password. Fix that, and you are good.

Comment: I just reformatted but for future readers, would a simple `ALTER ROLE postgres with password *****` solve it? Because it didn't work for me (ie. the scripts kept popping up)

Comment: @puk Once somebody has taken control of your machine it is game over. You shouldn't trust yourself to be able to find and remove all the code and back doors. Wipe the machine and reinstall the operating system, and choose good passwords on that new system.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on my VPS. I considered to reinstall OS or clone VPS, but have alot of issues on that solution. So, i choose another way:
I did:

- backup all data with "pg_dumpall"
- backup pqsql configuration(pg_hba.conf,postgresql.conf,...)
- Uninstall "everything" of pgsql
- reinstall pgsql
- restore pgsql data
- Done

Comment: And then the attackers hacked back into your system using the same passwords that you just backed up and restored....