# Solution for user postgres launches process allocate 2405% of CPU

Tags: postgresql, security, centos, cpu, postgis

After install Postgresql-11 and POSTGIS on my server then I realize that the CPU is higher ~ 2405% of it.

My situation is similare to: 
[user postgres launches process that takes all CPUs 100% usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149034/user-postgres-launches-process-that-takes-all-cpus-100-usage)

the solution proposed in the above post is that : **Take the machine from the internet, wipe it clean and re-install the operating system.**

My question is what Can I do to resolve this problem without re-install the operating system ?

Here's an [htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5jiC.png)

Comment: Is the server open to the Internet? What does top or ps ax show?

Comment: I added a snapshot to my post showing htop output

Comment: So is the Postgres server open to the Internet?

Comment: yes, but Today I change the configuration by setting : ```listen_addresses = 'localhost'```

Comment: Alright, but the damage is done. I would consider the machine compromised. If it where me I would wipe the machine and start over. @jjanes answer has another option, but that assumes that nothing more then a cryptocurrency miner was installed. It's up to you to whether you think that is the case and whether you are willing to risk it.

Answer (score 1):

You never know what backdoor someone might have installed, hence the advice to reinstall.  But pragmatically speaking, they are probably doing nothing more than mining cryptocurrency.  Simply securing all your PostgreSQL accounts with strong passwords or inactivating/deleting them (including accounts the attackers might have created themselves) and rebooting the OS would then be enough to get them out and keep them out.  But if the database server doesn't need to be exposed to the internet, don't expose it.

Comment: I secured all postgres's users (user1, postgres, and nosuperuser) with a strong password  then reboot the OS also I keep Postgres just locally BUT it keep showing once in a while. I scaned the process with ```lsoft``` 
```COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
tKz9BD 39730 postgres cwd DIR 9,2 4096 2 /
tKz9BD 39730 postgres 2u sock 0,7 0t0 1342891274 protocol: TCP
tKz9BD 39730 postgres 10u IPv4 1342891281 0t0 TCP 5.20.120.142:41882->160.16.111.233:webcache (ESTABLISHED)
tKz9BD 39730 postgres 11u IPv4 1343397496 0t0 TCP 5.20.120.142:57810->94.176.237.229:https (SYN_SENT)```