# kthreaddk in postgres uses high cpu

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu

I used Postgres in node.js project but my cpu is 100% in ubuntu server

I used this command

```
killall -9 kthreaddk
```

I stopped my project and stop `postgresql service`, after killing `kthreaddk` cpu is 0% but after 30 second `kthreaddk` run again and cpu will be 100% agian

what is `khtreaddk` and how to stopped it forever?

I try many ways that here is in stackoverflow but I can't solve it

[image]

Comment: You probably got hacked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149034/user-postgres-launches-process-that-takes-all-cpus-100-usage

Comment: why do you think I got hacked? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I don't think _you_ hacked. You **got** hacked. Someone broke into your computer and was able to log into your postgres database. Most probably because you are allowing remote superuser connections (bad idea) and have a really weak superuser password (extremely bad idea)

Comment: oh thank you@a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kthreaddk` is started by cron job. After it runs, it usually places its code in different directories and keeps updating crontab all the time.

To get rid of it follow these steps:

1. Identify which user crontab is running it.

```
$ cd /var/spool/cron/crontabs
# Preview each file here, e.g.
$ cat www-data
* * * * * /run/c8aaf4bea
```

The `/run/c8aaf4bea` looks weird, but do not remove it yet...

2. Block specific user from updating crontab (e.g. `www-data`). Edit `cron.deny` file

```
$ sudo vim /etc/cron.deny
```

and add a user name

```
www-data
```

Now the `threaddk` process is not able to edit crontab anymore.

3. Kill all the `threaddk` processes

```
$ sudo pkill -9 threaddk
```

4. Remove suspected line from the crontab

```
$ sudo vim /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
* * * * * /run/c8aaf4bea     <- remove this line
```

5. Remove the user from `cron.deny` file

Answer (score 3):

It's miner. It use crontab for restart(start) itself.

```
crontab -u postgres -l
```

I have similar problem. Just remove job from crontab and restart server imidiatly

Answer (score 2):

I had miner on my vps. My CPU usage was always 100%. First moment i was thinking i have memory leak in my java app or tomcat. I could kill process but it was starting another one in few seconds. In my case it was on user account which i didn't use. I killed all user processes with `pkill -u username` and then fast deleted user by `sudo deluser --remove-home username` before miner started its' processes. After this vps worked fine. Maybe it will help someone.